# Create your own custom browser

Tags: firefox, browser, google-chrome

I want to shape my own browser or at least modify a existing one so far that it meets my needs.

I want a fast browser (starting and running, not necessarily faster rendering) without any stuff I don't use and simple productive navigation (like Firefox + Vimperator + Tree Style Tab), only much more integrated into each other and a different GUI.

I was thinking about just looking into the current two top browsers chrome and firefox (open-source wise) and branch my own smaller version out of it.

By just using WebKit or Gecko I will have to implement all the Connection-stuff, too, but I really am not interested in doing that.

So my questions are:

1. Does it make sense to start off with a current browser and strip off certain features and the frontend and replace it with my own code?
2. Chrome or Firefox?  Which one is less complex?  I don't care much about Plugins and Extensions, so they aren't they pretty much even in features otherwise?

Thanks for your answers

p.s.:  It's a just-for-fun at-home project, so please no "just use the browsers..."-stuff...

Comment: i'm not saying "just use chrome"...but chrome is about as light as it gets. what else could you possibly want to strip away?

Comment: With Chrome I want to add Treestyle tabs and vim(perator) like navigation.  Chome is still not extensible enough to fit everything I want to do with it - i.e. I cannot change the GUI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best point would be looking at the webkit project: http://webkit.org/.

This is basically the **skeleton for a browser** or a **framework to create a new browser**.

Safari and konqueror were build using the webkit framework.

Comment: Isn't Webkit only the rendering engine?  So I would have to take care for encryption, connection handling etc myself?

Comment: Nope, (IIRC) Webkit compiles into a full blown browser.

Comment: Ok, I will take a look at it, thanks.

Btw, what does IIRC stand for?

Comment: IIRC means "if I recall correctly".

Answer (score 3):

K-Meleon is an open source webbrowser that you're free to do as you like with. it's light weight and very easy to work with. I was looking at doing the same as you but decided on making my own in vb.

http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

SeaMonkey is a very fast browser

http://www.seamonkey-project.org